# Type Hinting in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

How do you indicate that an element in an array is a DateTime object?

```
$row[$key]['new']->format('Ymd')
```

I tried with this because it did not work.

```
/** @var \DateTime $row[$key]['new'] */
```

Comment: You cannot (PHPDoc has no syntax for that) -- use intermediate variable (which you can easily typehint) if you need. Or use objects (custom classes) instead of arrays.

Comment: Please vote for the feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33651 .